# Swift 'text' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7. textLabel does not work

Tags: swift, xcode6

I keep having this error

[image]

I've seen other questions been answered by using textLabel.text, but it doesn't work in my case

[image]

I'm new to swift so could someone please explain me why and how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap `textLabel` by using an `!` after `textLabel`.

This is because `textLabel` is an `Optional` (hence the `textLabel?` type instead of just `textLabel`). Read more about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485).

Hope that helps!